# PyCharm: enable whisperer for modules created by Boost.Python

Tags: boost, pycharm

I just created a Python module from C++ with Boost.Python. It seems to work fine. The only thing which annoys me a bit is when I import it in PyCharm, it underlines the name of the module with red color. When I run the script, everything works fine.

Sure, I can ignore the unresolved reference, but that is not what I want because I would like the whisperer to work.

My question is: Is it even possible to "teach" PyCharm to whisper function, classes etc. of my module? And if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does PyCharm give unresolved reference errors on some Numpy imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689183/why-does-pycharm-give-unresolved-reference-errors-on-some-numpy-imports)