# PyCharm- AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arange'

Tags: python

I've just installed a NumPy in my computer and everything in Python consol is OK- https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFC4O.png

but in every interpreter i have the same problem:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANxG2.png

Thanks for help!

Comment: Post text, not screeshots. Can't copy a screenshot

Comment: It's because you named your filename itself as numpy, you shouldn't name your classes or functions after standard libraries(which you imported in this case) or inbuilt functions

Answer (score 8):

You called your program file `numpy.py` so the file is trying to import itself rather than the real `numpy` module. Call your file something like `numpy_test.py` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure you use the correct Python path.
2. If other attributes works well?
3. you should check this link first [Why does PyCharm give unresolved reference errors on some Numpy imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689183/why-does-pycharm-give-unresolved-reference-errors-on-some-numpy-imports)